# Start gas x86 n get segfault?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, att

Help I can't understand why get segfault.

```
void *cp1(void *a, const void *b, size_t c){
    c=0;
    asm volatile(
    "movl $0x1,0x10(%%ebp)\n\t"
    :::);
    printf("n %zu\n",c);
}
```

I try objdump and get this,

```
mov $0x0,0x10(%%ebp)\n\t ; this c=0
mov $0x1,0x10(%%ebp)\n\t ; this code from my asm volatile, n cause segfault
```

Why do I get seg fault on my asm code?

Comment: The function definition Void *cp1(void *a, const void *b, size_t c){
c=0; does not make sense because the argument of the parameter c is notf used.

Comment: Not used? Eemmm, var c become used if i used it in rvalue. If lvalue var c, not used.

Comment: I'm try n=n+1; but same, i get segfault

Comment: @AbuRisqi How would `movl` give you `n = n + 1` ? BTW: Do you mean `c = c + 1`? BTW: Are you on a 32 bit system?

Comment: @AbuRisqi What makes you think that the offset is `0x10`?

Comment: Im dump file C=0; is movl $0x0, 0x10(%ebp); from this, i find location param c on memory, then manual try init param c = 1, by location from c= 0

Comment: Yes 32 bit system

Comment: And I am read, Location parameter by reference manual gcc at&t, location param start from 0x08+ebp, param 2 0xc+ebp, param 3 0x10+ebp

Answer (score 0):

After hours, im compare file output gcc, on asm file .s the offset of parameter not use ebp but esp, i find this
Param 1 12(%esp)
Param 2 16(%esp)
Param 3 20(%esp)

But on my code
Param 3 is 0x10(%ebp)

This happen maybe coz, gcc not parse my asm, but just copy, because im not use operand input/output on my code.
Gcc treat my code as asm basic not extended.
And just copy paste to file .s.

Comment: But still i can't change value var c